# NSFetchedResultsController sorted by a one-to-many relation

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have three object types in CoreData; ObjectA, ObjectB and ObjectC. These objects are related with one-to-many relations like this:

`[ObjectA]--E[ObjectB]--E[ObjectC]`

What I try to accomplish, is to make a NSFetchedResultsController grouped by a property in ObjectA, and sorted by a property in ObjectC.

How the sort should work:
- In ObjectC there is a date property; lastUpdated. ObjectA will have a connection to several ObjectC´s, and by that several lastUpdated´s.
- My NSFetchedResultsController will display ObjectA, sorted by these lastUpdated´s.
- The ObjectA with the most recent updated ObjectC should appear first. 
- I am just interested in the ObjectC of an ObjectA with the most recent lastUpdated value.

Is this possible with NSFetchedResultsController and CoreData?

I assume that an alternative is to make a NSFetchedProperty on ObjectA reffering to ObjectC, but that would perhaps not be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with a single `NSFetchRequest`. You could get close by using `NSExpression`s and `setPropertiesToFetch:`, but not quite since you can't nest collection operators in key-value coding.

Your best bet will be to make an `NSFetchedProperty` on ObjectA which gets the associated (through ObjectB) ObjectC with the most recent `lastUpdated`. And in order to implement that, your best bet will be to make an `NSFetchedProperty` on **ObjectB** which gets the associated ObjectC with the most recent `lastUpdated`.

Comment: I have now tried the approach with `NSFetchedProperty`, but it does not seem to work. I can not sort by a fetched property in `NSFetchedResultsController` I just get an error 'keypath fetchedPropertyName not found in entity <NSSQLEntity ObjectA id=3>'

Comment: I guess you'll have to make it a regular property instead of a fetched property, and just make sure to update the property whenever the relationships change. Or, you'll have to stop using `NSFetchedResultsController` and do your sorting manually.